# (EMGU) How do I split and merge an Image?

Tags: c#, image-processing, merge, split, emgucv

I am working in C# on Visual Studio with Emgu.

I am doing a several image manipulations on a large image. I had the idea of splitting the image in half, doing the manipulations in parallel, them merging the image.

In pursuit of this goal, I have found a number of questions regarding the acquisition of rectangular parts of images for processing as well as splitting an image into channels (RGB, HSV, etc). I have not found a question that addresses the task of taking an image, and making it into two images. I have also not found a question that addresses taking two images and tacking them together.

The following code is what I would like to do, where split and merge are imaginary methods to accomplish it.

```
Image<Bgr,Byte> ogImage = new Image<Bgr, byte>(request.image);
Image<Bgr,Byte> topHalf = new Image<Bgr, byte>();
Image<Bgr,Byte> bottomHalf = new Image<Bgr, byte>();

ogImage.splitHorizonally(topHalf,bottomHalf);

//operations

ogImage = topHalf.merge(bottomHalf);
```

This is the type of question I hate asking, because it is simple and you would think it has a simple, easily available solution, but I have not found it, or I have found it and not understood it.

Comment: To split the image in half, create two new images each half the size of the original, and then draw each half of the original to each new image. To merge, draw the 2 smaller images in the correct positions on the original image.

Comment: @0liveradam8 Do you mind if I ask what you mean by draw? Is it a command? Or do you mean doing a pixel to pixel draw

Comment: I am not familiar with emgu so I do not know what commands you have available; I have used System.Drawing.Graphics with which you can do exactly as I have described with the commands. I was only trying to describe some logical steps you could take to try and achieve this.

Comment: @0liveradam8 I was hoping to avoid writing in that manner but it seems it is unavoidable. Thank you!

Comment: describe these "several image manipulations". you are looking to ***parallelize***, not to split anything. in the process of parallelizing, the "kernel" is run in parallel on multiple pieces of the picture. you asked the wrong question, unfortunately. you are asking for OpenMP or other libraries. be aware that some of the answers you're getting will not know anything about how to parallelize programs, they will only answer your literal question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to solve this but here is what I did. I took the easiest way out ;-)

```
    Mat lena = new Mat(@"D:\OpenCV\opencv-3.2.0\samples\data\Lena.jpg", 
                       ImreadModes.Unchanged);

    CvInvoke.Imshow("Lena", lena);

    System.Drawing.Rectangle topRect = new Rectangle(0, 
                                                     0, 
                                                     lena.Width,
                                                     (lena.Height / 2));

    System.Drawing.Rectangle bottomRect = new Rectangle(0, 
                                                        (lena.Height / 2),
                                                        lena.Width,
                                                        (lena.Height / 2));

    Mat lenaTop = new Mat(lena, topRect);

    CvInvoke.Imshow("Lena Top", lenaTop);

    Mat lenaBottom = new Mat(lena, bottomRect);

    CvInvoke.Imshow("Lena Bottom", lenaBottom);

    Mat newLena = new Mat();

    CvInvoke.VConcat(lenaBottom, lenaTop, newLena);

    CvInvoke.Imshow("New Lena", newLena);

    CvInvoke.WaitKey(0);
```

**Original Lena**

[image: Lena Original]

**Lena Top Half**

[image: Lena Top Half]

**Lena Bottom Half**

[image: Lena Bottom Half]

**The New Lena Rearranged**

[image: New Lena]

Answer (score 1):

Your goal isn't splitting an image. Your goal is to ***parallelize some operation*** on the image.

You did not disclose the specific operations you need to perform. That is important to know however, if you want to parallelize those operations.

You need to learn about strategies for parallelization in general. Commonly, a "kernel" is executed on several partitions of the data in parallel.

One practical approach is called ***OpenMP***. You apply "pragmas" to your own loops and OpenMP spreads those loop iterations across different threads.